# jQuery get all href urls in a document and truncate or split them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, split

This is driving me bonkers.

I have an ebay store menu which is created dynamically via php.

The urls look like this:

```
 http://stores.ebay.co.uk/somestore/Golf-Shoes-/_i.html?_fsub=3831075010
```

There are several of these, and for some reason my split is not working, I am trying to remove the data after the last slash.

```
    $('.MenuItem a:odd').each(function() {
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    $href.split('_')[1];
    console.log($href);
});
```

By my logic that should return: http://stores.ebay.co.uk/somestore/Golf-Shoes-/

I've made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/HA793/1/

I cant be too far off. I've tried splitting by other characters too to test the theory, and nothing seems to work. Where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're missing is an assignment operator

`$href = $href.split('_')[0];`

Answer (score 3):

Straight out of the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

> Unlike in languages like C, JavaScript strings are immutable. This
>   means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it.
>   However, it is still possible to create another string based on an
>   operation on the original string.

The split has no effect on the string it is splitting. Instead assign the first part of your split to a variable like so

```
var part = $href.split('_')[0];
```

You could also use the last slash as your point of reference like so

```
var part = $href.substring( 0, $href.lastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1 );
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HA793/7/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.MenuItem a:odd').each(function () {
    var href = this.href.split('_')[0];
    console.log(href);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HA793/6/)

- Get the href using `this.href`
- Split the href with the char `'_'`
- Get the first part of the array using `split('_')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result of the split operation to a variable to use it later on.

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
href = href.split('_')[0];
console.log(href);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HA793/5/

Additionally I'd suggest to only use the $ variable name prefix, when the result is actually a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign result of split to your variable $href:

```
$('.MenuItem a:odd').each(function() {
var $href = $(this).attr('href');
$href = $href.split('_')[0] + $href.split('_')[1];
console.log($href);
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php